# Ubuntu 18.04 Not entire RAM is used but 2/4GB of swap is used,

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, performance

So I have been working hard to optimize my Ubuntu Server 18.04 runing LEMP with everything up-to-date, including latest kernel updates and I have noticed some small delays in SSH responsiveness.

My idea is pointed towards RAM and SWAP usage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hagZM.jpg

In the link above there are screenshots of free -m, htop and vmstat.
I am not entirely sure what is going on here, not the entire RAM is used, but over 2GB of SWAP is used?...

I see 2 possibilities here:

1. I am actually running out of ram and ubuntu is using a lot of this 2GB swap and keeps a small amount of free memory for impotant tasks.
2. I am actually not using a lot of ram and ubuntu is just using SWAP to make the performance better.

I have doubts though and I would prefer if somebody could point me in the right understanding here.

I have also set swappiness to 5 and vfs_cache_pressure to 50, to use as little SWAP as possible, quite a while ago now.

Could this situation be the cause of my SSH being slow?
ex:

entering password on my local PC in terminal - I can type as fast as I possibly can and it will work

entering password on the remote server via SSH - I can not type the password as fast as I can as it will tell me invalid password.

I am using shift while entering the password, but it shouldn't cause me to enter invalid password when the SSH is slow.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your case that most of the memory is used, just not for programs.  In general, Linux will prefer to swap out parts of a program in order to leave some memory for buffers and page cache.

Although this may seem counter-intuitive, it actually makes performance a lot better.  Talking to the disk tends to be a couple of orders of magnitude slower than talking to memory, so keeping some disk cache in memory can improve performance very significantly.  This is normal and you should not need to adjust the swappiness or cache pressure in any way, and you should undo any changes you've made to those settings.

The reason you're seeing delays when typing over SSH is likely due to network issues.  When you're using SSH interactively, you want low latency: that is, the most important thing is to have the packets sent as quickly as possible, even if that means the amount of data you can send is much lower.  Somewhere along the line, your packets are taking longer to make the round-trip than they should.

There are a bunch of reasons this could be the case, but a lot of it depends where your server is located.  If it's far away, latency will be higher.  Also, if the network is congested somewhere along the way, you'll also see some lag.

The tool one typically uses to troubleshoot these kinds of problems is `mtr`.  You can run `mtr -t YOUR_SERVER` and see if there's any latency problems.

If there's no latency problems, then it is possible that your server being low on memory is the problem, but in that case your solution needs to be to add memory, not to tinker with kernel parameters.  It's obvious from your image that you're well exceeding the memory capacity of the server and you either need to add more or use less.

Comment: I agree with much of this post (ie about memory usage), but not the part about SSH.  I expect that the server is swapping like crazy (because it is memory strarved as seen by the amount of swap). and when SSH is kicking it it is exacerbating the the swap to load ssh and the libraries it is calling.  The "I can not type the password as fast as I can" implies its NOT a networking problem as the network should buffer the keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you for your throughout explanation.
How exactly did you make out that my server is low on memory, based on those photos?
Why do I have to change those values? My idea was to use as little swap as possible, since I am bounded by 2GB of RAM for now, aren't those values helpful in my scenario?
I contacted the hosting with the MTR already, but I still don't get it. as @davidgo mentioned keystrokes should be buffered, but somehow they aren't?
My server is located within 26ms ping range, ping's not the problem. SFTP transfers are really fast, but SSH and going through dirs sometime"lags".

Comment: You've got 4.1 GB (2.8 GB of swap and 1.3 GB of phyiscal memory) committed and 2 GB of physical ram.  Ideally your working set can fit into memory.  And SFTP doesn't need low latency but instead high throughput.

Comment: SSH "going through dir lagtimes" implies heavy disk IO, which is consistent with the system swapping. With a low VM.swappiness Linux uses swap more-or-less as a last resort. Your swap figures show 2.9 gigs used (in multiple places). On a healthy system with low VM.swappiness the figure should be less then 1/10th that.

Comment: BTW, Experience has shown me a low number for VM.swappiness is important for a responsive server - although Ive not tested if its slightly less performant overall. Other then constraining programs to use a lot less memory or adding more ram, no amount of tuning will fix your problem.